# How to make sure a stopped weblogic queue doesn't start back up with a server reboot?

Tags: weblogic, message-queue

I am working with a traditional java application with ejbs, MDBs and using weblogic server. Our processing logic is embedded in queues. However, when something goes wrong, we have provided ability from a webpage to stop a queue indefinitely. The queue can be resumed once the issues are resolved.

Now the issue arises, if the server restarts while the queue was intentionally turned off. When the server restarts, the queue starts back up and continues with the processing logic even though its not fixed yet. Can anyone suggest how to deal with this ? I would want a stopped queue to remain stopped even if the server restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this issue by having a singleton ejb that keeps track of what state the queue is supposed to be in...

modified code to always check this ejb at the end of the maintenance window